# Nontriviality of pullback of tangent bundle on the Möbius bundle

Tags: vector-bundles

Consider the Möbius strip $M$ as a vector bundle over $\mathbb R$, in which it is embedded as the zero section. We have the tangent bundle $TM$ over $M$. How to prove that the pullback of this to $\mathbb R$ is nontrivial?

Comment: Any vector bundle over $\Bbb R$ is trivial. $M$ is not the zero section of any vector bundle over $\Bbb R$ because the zero section of such a bundle would be homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ but $M$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.